# WinHttpSendRequest fails when running from a service

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to call WinHttpSendRequest from a program of mine that runs as a service. The function fails with error 12029.
If I run it normally (not as a service), the function succeeds.
I know WinInet is not supposed to be used in a service, but I though WinHttp should work fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: The error code is `ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT`. What arguments do you provide to this API call?

Comment: I provide the handle from the WinHttpOpenRequest API and all the others are nulls. As I said, the call succeeds when not running from within a service.

Comment: The succeeding "not service" call does not explain the problem. You need to look at your API calls that lead to failure - bad argument on this or preceding calls.

Comment: What user are you running the service under?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Hi David, I know It's been a while, but I have the same problem. My service is running under SYSTEM.